# Can we control the Wasserstein metric between $\mu$ and $\nu$ by their moment difference?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, optimal-transportation, wasserstein-distance

Fix $p \in [1, \infty)$. Let $(\mathcal P_p(\mathbb R^d), W_p)$ be the Wasserstein space of all Borel probability measures on $\mathbb R^d$ with finite $p$-th moment. Let $D_p$ be the collection of all Borel measurable functions $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R^d} f (x) \, \mathrm d x = 1$ and $\int_{\mathbb R^d} f (x) |x|^p \, \mathrm d x < \infty$. So $f \in D_p$ if and only if $f$ is a density of some $\mu \in \mathcal P_p(\mathbb R^d)$.

Let $\Psi : D_p \to \mathcal P_p(\mathbb R^d)$ be the map that sends a density to its measure. For $\alpha \in (0, 1]$, we define
$$
[f-g]_p^\alpha := \left ( \int_{\mathbb R^d} |f(x)-g(x)| \, |x|^p \, \mathrm d x \right ) ^\alpha,
\quad \forall f,g \in D_p.
$$

> Are there constants $\alpha, C>0$ (possibly depending on $d, p$) such that
> $$
> W_p (\Psi(f), \Psi(g)) \le C [f-g]_p^\alpha,
> \quad \forall f,g \in D_p.
> $$
> ?

Thank you so much for your elaboration?

Comment: Equation 2 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.03152.pdf) gives a bound which seems similar to the reverse of what you are looking for (though with the absolute value outside the integral rather than inside).

Comment: @Mark That makes a big difference. Indeed, we can [pick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440772/is-this-map-from-the-space-of-probability-densities-to-the-wasserstein-space-l?rq=1) $C=\alpha=1$ in case $p=1$.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4835341/quantitative-bound-on-wasserstein-distances-by-lp-distances) looks like what you want

Comment: @Mark This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much for your help!